# I have a Web From built with Flask WTForms which when submitted need to create a Jira Issue

Tags: jira, flask-wtforms, jira-rest-api

I am open to try out the jira REST API, but i am not a PRO programmer. So i was wondering if there are any examples or any snippets available for me to use. I have the Web Form built in Flask, so it will be helpful if you can provide a python code preferably.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about Jira Cloud REST APIs in [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2). Each API have code samples for cURL, Java, Node.js, Python, and PHP.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll have a look at this.